# What does interaction of continuous and categorical variable represent (Stata)?

Tags: stata, interaction

Here is a quotation from a Stata online tutorial: **If you want to interact a continuous variable with a factor variable, just prefix the continuous variable with c.** http://www.stata.com/capabilities/overview/factor-variables/

They give the following example: `smoker#c.bmi`.

`smoker` is a categorical variable, coded as 1 non-smoker, 2 smoker, 3 heavy smoker.

`bmi` is a continuous variable, body mass index.

When they create interaction term `smoker#c.bmi`, what does it show and how is it to be interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that `smoker` is a dummy variable (1/0) [please see the note below]. Please double check the following sentence:

We run a linear regression of cholesterol level on a full factorial of age group and *whether the person smokes* along with a continuous body mass index (bmi) and its interaction with *whether the person smokes* [emphasis]

```
cholesterol = -0.517 smoker + 0.03455 bmi + 0.0245 bmi*smoker + other parts
```

The coefficient on `bmi` indicates the impact of `bmi` for non-smoker whereas the coefficient on `bmi*smoker` gives the incremental impact of `bmi` for smoker (i.e. for smoker it is 0.03455 + 0.0245 vs 0.03455 for non-smoker). The significance of the interaction term indicates that impact on cholesterol of `bmi` is higher for smokers than for non-smokers.

Note: There are three categories of age group, not three categories of smokers.